# Cannot login on ChatGPT mobile website (chat.openai.com) on iOS 14/iPadOS 14

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

I used to use the mobile site (chat.open.com) just fine. However, starting from two weeks ago, all the browsers on my iPhone (iOS 14) and iPad (iPadOS 14) cannot log into my chatGPT account successfully. There is no response at all after I click on the log in/sign up button on this page:

[image: ChatGPT Mobile Login Page]

All the browsers on my iPhone and iPad won't work. I can still log in on my laptop's browser though. I have talked to some people who are using ios16 on their iPhones and they don't have this problem. I can't update my iOS/iPadOS because my iPhone and iPad are of older models and updating them to newer OS version will make the battery run out faster. The ChatGPT app also only supports iOS/iPadOS 16.

- I can’t upgrade to iOS 16 due to hardware support for old devices.
- I don’t want to upgrade any iOS due to concerns about battery life being less on new OS.
- The "request desktop site" feature on all my iPhone/iPad browsers fails to solve this issue.

Is there anyway that I can still log into the mobile webpage of chatGPT while staying on my current iOS/iPadOS?

Comment: Same issue, and my diagnosis coincides with that of the other answers: safari in iOS 14 fails to parse the JS there (as well as bing-chat which has the same issue now…) Just as you, I don’t intend to update beyond iOS 14 due to battery consumption (mine already is below 70% capacity). Since I am about to give up and write a Python script to query chatGPT and run it inside Pythonista, before I do, have you found any workaround since the original post?

Comment: @EMJzero Not really. If you look up on Reddit, some people say you can jailbreak your iPhone and download some particular browser that is compatible with ChatGPT. But I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 14 is failing to parse the JavaScript on the site. It sees a syntax error in the main JavaScript, bundle, causing it to fail to load the bundle, which contains all the main JavaScript required for the page.

[image]

You need to update iOS, or OpenAI need to fix their website.

Comment: I appreciate it! What is the development tool you are using to simulate the iphone 6s behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The new interface doesn't work on Safari 14, Mojave either.

Try [Chrome](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id535886823?pt%3D9008%26ct%3Dhelp-center-mg%26mt%3D8) [which *does* still work on Mac], otherwise you'll have to update iOS.

Comment: Is there any workaround besides updating iOS or jailbreaking the iPhone?

Comment: As you can't update Safari without updating the OS, no.